# Do Django Model Managers require using=self._db

Tags: python, django, database

In working with the Django user model I've noticed model managers include a `using=self._db` parameter when acting on a database. If I'm only using a single database, is this necessary? What does `using=self._db` do other than specify the database. Is this specified as a fail-safe in the event another database is added?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Managers use that parameter to define on which database the underlying queryset the manager uses should operate on. This is simply there to optionally override it in case you have e.g. multiple databases and you want your manger/queryset to operate on a specific one.

Comment: In the event `using=self._db` is left out, how does the Manager know what database to act on if there are more than one database? Trying to understand the inner-workings of Django.

Comment: There must be one database defined as default in the settings. [See this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases) for details. This database will be used by default when `using` is not explicitly set. If set `using` expects a string which is the key to the database settings defined in the `DATABASE` settings dict.