# What is the value of self._db by default in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-2.2

Please see the following code:
    `user.save(using=self._db)`
What is the default value of self._db for Django?
Does this value default to what I've specified under default for database in my settings.py?

I've found questions on Stack Overflow that say this value will provide a database type to Django, but if I've never set it explicitly, what is it by default?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do Django Model Managers require using=self.\_db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173347/do-django-model-managers-require-using-self-db)

Answer (score 35):

Django default managers use `using` parameter to define which database underlying the manager should use for operation. This will optionally use. This is used in case you have multiple databases by which you define which database you need to use for operation.

An example `user.save(using=self._db)` usually defined as "default" from your database configuration in `settings.py`. For more info [click here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/manager.py#L31)

Behind the scene `self._db` set as `None`. If `user.save(using=None)`, then it will use `default database.`

For example, your database configuration is like

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'app_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'postgres_user',
        'PASSWORD': '****'
    },
    'new_users': {
        'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': '****'
    }
}
```

Then if you want to use default database then use `user.save(using=self._db)`
If you want to use `new_users` database then use `user.save(using="new_users")`

Comment: Nice explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Its default value is specified in `settings.py`

as

`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}`

as mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases)

Answer (score 1):

**Django** default managers use `using` parameters to define which database underlying the manager should use for operation. This will optionally use. This is used in case you have multiple databases by which you define which database you need to use for operation.

An example `user.save(using=self._db)` is usually defined as "default" from your database configuration in `settings.py`.

Behind-the-scene `self._db` set as `None`. If `user.save(using=None)`, then it will use the `default database`.

For example, your database configuration is like

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'app_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'postgres_user',
        'PASSWORD': '****'
    },
    'new_users': {
        'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': '****'
    }
}
```

Then if you want to use default database then use `user.save(using=self._db)` If you want to use `new_users` database then use `user.save(using="new_users")`